# pgfplots outputs slope of the line differently than it actually is

Tags: pgfplots, positioning

I drew a line that lies on points (0,3) and (3,0) so the slope is -1. Then I drew two points on that line at (1,2) and (2,1) to represent hypotenuse of an (imaginary) isosceles triangle between them. Then I drew a point at (1,1) to be a point where (imaginary) lines extending from the previously described points would touch, forming (imaginary) isosceles triangle. *Note: I call the triangle "imaginary" because there are no lines drawn from the points on the line to the connecting (straight angle) point (which is below the line).*

Now comes the problematic part. The point that connects the (imaginary) lines from the points that lie on the slope line should be located at a place where the (imaginary) lines would be of equal length but it is not at the correct location.

**Why is the output different from what is expected and defined by data? What can be done to correct this?**

Here is pgfplots generated output with the false isosceles triangle (I added red lines in digital imaging software to indicate what should have been the correct placement of points to form the isosceles triangle; you can see the gap after the horizontal red line):

[image]

Comment: It's impossible to tell without seeing the code that generated the figure, but I'll hazard a guess and say that your axes aren't scaled equally. Add `axis equal` or `axis equal image` to the `axis` options to correct this.

Comment: Jake, it works! Thank you.

Would you mind copying your comment and pasting it as an answer? You should get points for this.